# Could not find endpoint element with name 'xxxxx' and contract 'yyy' in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: c#, web-services, soap-client

I generated a proxy via this command - 
            **svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService?wsdl**

and then copied the elements from the resulting app.config into the app.config file of an existing project.

When I try to access the client in that config file via-

**MHSClient serviceProxy = new MHSClient("MHSPort");**

it should reference the second client below:

```
  <client>
  <endpoint address="https://webservices.hmsa.com/EDI27X/cstc/Hipaa27XService.svc"
            binding="customBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpoint" 
            contract="HIPAA27XServiceContract" 
            name="wsHttpEndpoint" />
  <endpoint address="https://12.23.28.113:9047/MHService" 
            binding="customBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="MHService_MHSPort" 
            contract="MHS"
            name="MHSPort" />
</client>
```

but instead I get the error;


**Could not find endpoint element with name 'MHSPort' and contract 'MHS' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.'**

If I go to definition of MHSClient, it takes me to the proxy.cs file and this line; 
    **public partial class MHSClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase, MHS**

**solved with the following- 

          endptAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("uri"/xxxx"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("xxxxxx"), addressHeaders);

            MHSClient serviceProxy = new MHSClient(b, endptAddress);**

Comment: are you able to access your service with the endpoint address in the config?

Comment: Excellent question @Gaunxi ! I just edited the post above to include the 3 lines of code at bottom. Don't I have to create the proxy or client first before I can access the service with the endpoint? And there are a few overloads for the endpoint and I'm not sure which one to use;

Comment: solved, although this process is so configuration dependent with so many layers that i can't say I fully understand why it works yet. interop on top of WS-Security within the context of various .NET and Visual Studio implementations of web services... oh my. EndpointAddress endptAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://12.23.28.113:9047/xxxxxx"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("xxxxxxxx"), addressHeaders);
 MHSClient serviceProxy = new MHSClient(b, endptAddress);

Answer (score 1):

solved with the following- 
**endptAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("uri"/xxxx"), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("xxxxxx"), addressHeaders); 


MHSClient serviceProxy = new MHSClient(b, endptAddress);**

**@Guanxi gave me the clue when asking about endpoint address from the config file.** 
 Once I created the endpoint address then I could instantiate/create the service using the correct overload;
 var b = new CustomBinding() as the first argument and for the second argument, 
the correct endpoint address. 
complicated - WS-Security - IBM Websphere server interop <-> wcf client 
 within the context of various .NET and Visual Studio implementations of web services... 
oh my

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the ConfigurationName property of the ServiceContractAttribute above the service contract interface, ConfigurationName should match your contract name.

```
'VB.NET:
Imports System.ServiceModel

<ServiceContract([Namespace]:="http://yournamespace", ConfigurationName:="MHS")> _
Public Interface MHS

//C#:
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://yournamespace", ConfigurationName="MHS")]
public interface MHS
```

Look at the auto generated code here:
[MSDN: How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also worth looking at:
[MSDN: ServiceContractAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.SERVICECONTRACTATTRIBUTE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)